# I got an error in derby connection in netbeans ide

Tags: netbeans

When I try to make a new project in java with the help of the derby database I got the error like "Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/week1DB using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041, SQLERRMC: Failed to create database 'week1DB', see the next exception for details.::SQLSTATE: XBM0H)"

Comment: Are you certain that the Derby server is running?

Comment: I don't know because I am new to derby...

Comment: OK, but being able to determine whether your DB server is running is critical to what you are doing, and it must be running in order to access your Derby database. Consider following the tutorial [Working with the Java DB (Derby) Database](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html) to get a better understanding of the basics of using Derby in NetBeans.